# How to check two instances are having same values in android?

Tags: java, android

How can I check 2 instances of same class are equal or not in android?

code is as below

```
class Address{
    int id;
    String name;
    String street;
    City city;
    State state;
    List<Language> languages;
}
class City{
    int cityId;
    String cityName;
}
class State{
    int stateId;
    String stateName;
}
class Language{
    int langId,
    String langName;
}

class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    .
    Address address1=new Address();
    .
    .
    Address address2=new Address();
    .
    .
    .

    **check address1 and address2 are having same values**
    .
    .
    .

    }

}
```

Kindly let me know the best way to check *address1* and *address2* instances are having same values or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `equals()` method of the Address class and then in that method return true if the values are same else false.
For more details:
http://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each value one by one

```
public bool compare(Addess a1, Address a2){

    if (a1.attribute1.equals(a2.attribute)){

       if(a1.attribute2.equals(a2.attribute)){
            // do this for all attributes
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way, without checking each and every attribute?